# Многократное изменение переменной по нажатию кнопки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть код:

```
<?php
$a = 10;

if (isset($_REQUEST['go'])) {
    $result = $a--;
}
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="<?=$a?>">
    <input type="submit" name="go">
</form>
```

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку после каждого следующего нажатия значение переменной "a" уменьшалось на 1. Возможно ли это сделать стандартными средствами php или только используя БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для хранения результата, к примеру сессии:

```
<?php

session_start();

!empty($_SESSION['result']) ?: $_SESSION['result'] = 10;
$a = '';

if (isset($_REQUEST['go'])) {
    $a = $_SESSION['result']--;
}

?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="<?=$a?>">
    <input type="submit" name="go">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало! До сессий ещё пока не дошёл. Буду дальше изучать.

Answer (score 0):

Надо где-то хранить данные, между запросами. Можно в БД, можно в сессионных переменных

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['data']) {
   $_SESSION['data'] = 10;
}
$_SESSION['data']--;
var_dump($_SESSION['data']);
```